# jQuery - function happening too soon or callback process confusion

Tags: jquery

Trying to `.slideUp()`, clear the element with `.html('')`, then repopulate the element and `.slideDown()`.  Simple?  Yes.  Working? No.

The element is repopulated before the slide up in complete.  Essentially, you see the magician leave before the curtain is in place which spoils the show.

**jsFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Zt6gw/

**jQuery**

```
$('#oh_sort').change(function(){
    $('#oh_list_cont').slideUp(1000);
    $('#oh_list_cont').promise().done(ohReset());
    $('#oh_list_cont').slideDown(1000);
});

function getOpenhouse(){
    var data = $('#oh_sort').val();
    if(data == 'date'){
        $('#oh_list_cont').append('WOOOOOOORK!');
    }
    if(data == 'price'){
        $('#oh_list_cont').append('Please?!');
    }
    if(data == 'city'){
        $('#oh_list_cont').append('OMGWTFBBQ');
    }
}

function ohReset() {
    $('#oh_list_cont').html('');
    getOpenhouse();
}
```

I've tried this with the [complete] (callback?) function built in to .slideUp(), but then nothing populates and the second slide animation doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are calling `ohReset()` immediately instead of passing it as a callback:

```
$('#oh_list_cont').promise().done(ohReset());
```

It should be:

```
$('#oh_list_cont').promise().done(ohReset);
```

Comment: Awesome.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#oh_sort' ).change( function()
{
    $( '#oh_list_cont' ).slideUp( 1000, function()
    {
        $( '#oh_list_cont' ).promise().done( ohReset() );
    } );
    $( '#oh_list_cont' ).slideDown( 1000 );
});
```

something like this?